# Is it possible to get wildcard value for ListenFor?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to add voice commands to my Windows Phone 8 app. One I'd like to add is "Find a record containing {wildcard}." I've included the following in my VCD:

```
<ListenFor>Find [a] record [containing] {*}</ListenFor>
```

But when my app navigates to the search page, the `reco` attribute of the QueryString has the value "Find a record containing ...". This is expected, according to [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206959(v=vs.105).aspx).

My question is, is there a way to retrieve the wildcard value, or was this not implemented in Windows Phone 8 Voice Commands? Searching only finds [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robch/archive/2012/11/08/wp8-voice-commands-wildcards.aspx), but it appears it applies to Windows Phone 8.1. At this point I'd like to stick with the 8.0 SDK until 8.1 adoption increases (plus I have a Universal App version in the works).

So is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation I've read is so busy promoting the latest and greatest (e.g., Cortana) that some details seem to be lost in the excitement.

Fortunately, I found, from [this article](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/blog/Cortana-show-me-how-I-can-add-you-to-my-apps):

> Windows Phone 8.0, our previous release, brought with it the Voice Commands feature.
>
> ...
>
> The biggest limitation of Voice Commands was that the full text of the commands themselves needed to be known ahead of time.

So the answer is that while Voice Commands in the 8.0 SDK allow for the wildcard, it doesn't do anything with it. Only the 8.1 SDK can parse it and pass the value on.